# Steal focus as SetForegroundWindow can't do it

Tags: winapi

I know this sounds evil but my intention is not this at all.

A user has clicked "delay shot" and a countdown starts, during that time they go focus another application, then after countdown user expects my app to take back focus.

`SetForegroundWindow` fails when it runs from appliction with PID X while application with PID Y is focused.

This worked to bring my window forward, but it doesn't get focus:

```
SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);
```

It sets the window to be always on top. However focus is not put into my window. And then setting it back to `HWND_NOTOPMOST` leaves it there, even though its not top most, but it still doesnt have focus. Running `SetForegroundWindow` won't do the trick after these calls to `SetWindowPos` Is there anyway to steal focus?

I have tried a combination of:

- `SwitchToThisWindow`
- `SetWindowPos`
- `ShowWindow`
- `SetForegroundWindow`

But can't seem to figure it out.

Another reason I think this has to be possible is because Mac OSX allows it with `NSApplication activateIgnoringOtherApps:` and Linux's allow it too. I'd like to get this cross platform.

As a last resort I was going to use the `HWND_TOPMOST` method, then `GetWindowRect` then `SetCursorPos` and send single click to my window at pos 0,0, I really don't want to though as there might be something at 0,0 and it shouldn't be auto clicked on.

Comment: Why don't you respect the user and respect the system design? User is going to be hacked off if they are typing into a document and suddenly find those key strokes being delivered to another window. One where the key strokes may have consequences.

Comment: Hmm, so your research showed that operating systems that just about nobody likes to use can do this so it must be possible in Windows as well.  Very compelling argument.  Just copy/paste the title of your question in the Google query box and the answer is on the first page.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx). You cannot steal focus, unless the other app **allows** you to steal it. This requires cooperation between the apps.

Comment: I know guys I am not a fan of the Linux or OSX distributions, but its a user friendly feature. my application takes a screenshot after count down. I don't mind doing hacky things as this is totally usr friendly. This is the behavior the user is expecting and asking for. I know in most cases this is evil but how else would you acheive this feature? I am able to launch exe which focus's my app, because on launch of software it steals focus, and then `SetForegroundWindow` from that to my thing works great. I just believe there has to be a coder frindlier way then exe or send click. +rep all you

Comment: It's odd that you won't believe the documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This always works, no matter what app is in foreground (like Task Manager, etc.):

```
AllocConsole(); 
auto hWndConsole = GetConsoleWindow();
SetWindowPos(hWndConsole, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER);
FreeConsole();
SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but this looks like it would work. Very cool solution I accepted it!

Comment: tested, still can't steal the focus and to show at top on windows 11 :(

Answer (score 1):

As the comment says, `SetForegroundWindow` is sometimes useless intentionally. Basically, two ways are used to bypass restrictions:

- Simulate keyboards / mouses
- Get privileges

There is some smarter magic to achieve the goal without directly clicking the window you are going to activate. Since I'm not familiar with GUI, I would suggest inject code directly into current foreground window and hand over the foreground right.

Besides there're some examples on simulating.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/76427/How-to-bring-window-to-top-with-SetForegroundWindo.aspx