# external application/ command line to change between firefox windows (not tabs) in WIN7?

Tags: c#, vb.net, firefox, command-line, firefox-addon

For an example lets say I have opened 2 Firefox windows (not tabs) 1st shall be google.com and other one is yahoo.com. if currently google is on foreground and i want to bring yahoo window to front using a command from a external program or a command line script how can I do it?

Comment: Which scripting language do you prefer?

Comment: this solution is for windows only, which i think is what you want: command line i dont know. but via the windows c api yes you can do this. You have to use winapi threading trick on `SetForgroundWindow`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031856/bring-firefox-window-to-the-front-using-firefox-addon?lq=1 to find the firefox window `hwnd`s you'll have to enumerate windows and test window class name if you need help with that let me know.